# Selenium tests in MSBuild scripts

Tags: selenium, msbuild

Is it possible to run Selenium scripts as a part of your deployment process in an MSBuild file?  I'm looking for sample MSBuild snipets if people have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your test framework wrapper? If it's one of [these supported](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gallio), check out http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_Gallio_MSBuildTasks_Gallio.htm

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Gallio" AssemblyFile="$(ProgramW6432)\Gallio\bin\Gallio.MsBuildTasks.dll" />

<Files Include="*Test*.dll" />

<Gallio
    Files="@(Files)"
    ReportTypes="xml"
    ReportDirectory="$(Directory)"
/>
```